# How to get submission ID while notarizing using notarytool on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, notarize, notary, notarization

I am working on notarizing my installer using notarytool, below is my command

```
submission_id=$(xcrun notarytool submit --apple-id "${APPLE_ID}" --team-id "${TEAM_ID}" --password "${APP_PASSWORD}" "${dmgFile}" 2>&1)
```

Next I want to check the status using notarytool info

```
status=$(xcrun notarytool info "${submission_id}" --apple-id "$APPLE_ID" --password "$APP_PASSWORD" 2>&1)
```

However, I get submission_id as below.

> Conducting pre-submission checks for *file_name*.*dmg* and initiating
> connection to the Apple notary service... Submission ID received id:
> *submission_id* Successfully uploaded file id: *submission_id* path:
> *file_path*/*file_name*.*dmg*

How can I extract submission_id in the form of UUID which I can use to get notarization status using notary info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I had to work on the Notarization via CI/CD. At the moment I'm writing the notarytool's output is similar to:

```
Conducting pre-submission checks for Boundle.dmg and initiating connection to the Apple notary service...
Submission ID received
  id: abc12-1234-xxxx-yyyy-123456e4c1c8
Upload progress: 100,00% (116 MB of 116 MB)    
Successfully uploaded file
  id: abc12-1234-xxxx-yyyy-123456e4c1c8
  path: /Users/Boundle.dmg
Waiting for processing to complete.
Current status: Accepted...........
Processing complete
  id: abc12-1234-xxxx-yyyy-123456e4c1c8
  status: Accepted
```

You can use the `awk` command to clean and retrieve only the id from the notary output:

```
submission_id=$(echo "$submission_id" | awk '/id: / { print $2;exit; }')
```

In my case the result was:

```bash
NOTARY_SUBMIT_OUTPUT=$(xcrun notarytool submit "${dmgFile}" --wait --apple-id "${APPLE_ID}" --password "${APP_PASSWORD}" --team-id "${TEAM_ID}")
xcrun notarytool log $(echo "$NOTARY_SUBMIT_OUTPUT" | awk '/id: / { print $2;exit; }') --apple-id "${APPLE_ID}" --password "${APP_PASSWORD}" --team-id "${TEAM_ID}"
```

**N.B.**: When using echo ensure to wrap your variable into double-quote to preserve line-breaks:

`echo "$NOTARY_SUBMIT_OUTPUT"`